# Progressively Loading Images with Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

If I opened this on a screen 800px wide, would both the small and big jpg be loaded? or is the browser intelligent enough to ignore the smaller image?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    div {
        background-image: url(images/small.jpg);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    div {
        background-image: url(images/big.jpg);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since both media queries will be fulfilled and both rules use the same selector, the second `div` rule will take precedence, and only `big.jpg` will be loaded for any `div`. Once you resize the browser window until the second rule no longer applies, it should go ahead and load `small.jpg`.

I made a quick test page with your CSS. Firebug's Net panel verified that `big.jpg` was being loaded at my usual browser size, and `small.jpg` only loaded once I made my browser window narrow enough.

Comment: Thanks bolt, you're a legend!